# Getting 405- Method not allowed in API Connect Management

Tags: apiconnect

I am facing an issue which say 
error -

```
 405- Method not Allowed. 
 The requested method PUT is not allowed for the URL /.
```

The scene is , before subscribing to an API in API Portal, you will need a Subscription Approval from the API Management (APIM) i.e. the Organization Owner. But in the approvals tab of APIM , when applying for approval i get this error -

[image: 405 - error]

Can it please be resolved ?

Comment: What version of API Connect are you using?

Comment: version 7.6.0.3

Comment: datapower version -  7.6.0.3 , IBM API Management Developer Portal (apim_profile-7.x-5.0.8.4-20180628-1446)

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you all the method in DataPower XML manager policy. I believe by default all the HTTP methods are allowed. If you creating XML manager manually make sure you all it in the XML manager configuration.

Thanks
SP